# How to run scala tests with junit 4?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, scala-2.8, junit4

I can't run following code with IDEA

```
@Test
class CompanyURLTest extends Assert {
  @Test
  def test = assert(false);

}
```

It runs, but J-Unit says that there are not test to run

Comment: Can you please tell more about test frameworks you're using? Is it plain JUnit or something else together with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally use ScalaTest in combination with the Junit4 runner so that Maven sees and executes my tests. I like the Spec/FlatSpec/WordSpec semantics for organizing tests. I'm experimenting with the ShouldMatchers but I have used JUnit for so long that asserts just seem a bit more natural to me.

Here's an example:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class BlogFeedHandlerTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with Logging {
    "the thingy" should "do what I expect it to do" in {
        val someValue = false;

        assert(someValue === false)
    }
}
```

The ScalaTest docs are at http://www.scalatest.org/

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me

```
import org.junit._
import Assert._

class MyTest {

    @Test
    def test = assert(false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The @org.junit.Test annotation is only applicable for methods: @Target({ElementType.METHOD}).
Also keep in mind that test methods must return Unit.

```
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.Test

class CompanyURLTest {
  @Test def test = assertFalse(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's late - Gradle site surprisingly has a lot of good tutorials showing how to support Scala tests.

https://guides.gradle.org/building-scala-libraries/#review_the_generated_project_files